# How to log SQL statements used by JOOQ generator maven plugin

Tags: maven, logging, jooq

When executing the JOOQ generator maven plugin, only the fetch results are logged, not the SQL statement itself.

```
mvn generate-sources -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=DEBUG  -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.level.org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener=DEBUG
```

I've tried with both, DEBUG and TRACE, TRACE only additionally logs every fetched record.
Within my applications (Spring Boot, Quarkus), there is no such problem: with log level

```
org.jooq=DEBUG
```

I see SQL statements, bind values and the record fetched.

my environment:

```
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3_1/libexec
Java version: 13.0.2
jooq-codegen-maven 3.13.14
```

Answer (score 1):

Some things you might try:

- Try adding the Maven `-X` or `--debug` flag to get debug log output from Maven plugins, see [Maven CLI options](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-embedder/cli.html)
- Try adding the `<logging>DEBUG</logging>` flag to your configuration: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-logging/

Comment: No, unfortunately the same result: only the results are logged: 

`[DEBUG] Fetched row(s)`

Comment: Same for using JDK 11.0.7 instead 13.

Comment: long done (honestly, this was my first shot) ... but no queries logged.

Comment: @Dominik: OK, sorry can't help then. This works for me. Perhaps, can you try to create an [MCVE](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ-mcve), and possibly file a bug?

Comment: with the fresh bootstraped MCVE everything works and the statements are logged after adding `<logging>DEBUG</logging> ` and starting mvn with `-X`. Seems that something is wrong within my quarkus project..

Comment: @LukasEder Thanks. This thread helped me realize why logging the SQL queries used in code generation didn't work for me - I had only `INFO` level enabled in my `logback.xml` config. :) Seeing that "it's supposed to work" was helpful.

Comment: @PerLundberg: Yes, logging all the queries at `INFO` level would be very verbose, and also likely cause GDPR compliance issues if you're going to log bind values (with customer identifying information) in productive log files...

Comment: @LukasEder Yep, definitely not a good thing. :) Codegen is a bit of a different thing (less likey to run into GDPR-compliance issues) but it's still a sensible default to leave it disabled by default since it spits out tons of logs for any normal-sized database.